# Async Generic Method causes "Could not load type '<MethodNameAsync>d__e`1' from assembly" error on Windows 2012

Tags: c#, .net, generics, async-await

We have a Web API which calls C# dlls deployed on a test server (Windows 2008) that is running without any issues.

When we deploy the exact same thing on a Windows 2012 server we get the following error when we try to access an asyncronous generic method:

```
Could not load type '<CallWebMethodAsync>d__e`1' from assembly 'Foo.Bar, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Here is an example of one of the methods:

```
    private async Task<TResponse> CallWebMethodAsync<TResponse>(string requestUri) 
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = Task.Run(() => httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri)).Result;

        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var jsonres = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(jsonres);
    }
```

So it is only when deployed to Windows 2012 that this error occurs.

It works if I change this so it is not generic, for example like so:

```
    private async Task<FooBar> CallWebMethodAsync(string requestUri) 
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = Task.Run(() => httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri)).Result; //HttpResponseMessage result = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri);

        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var jsonres = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FooBar>(jsonres);
    }
```

Both the Windows 2008 and the Windows 2012 have .NET 4.5.2 installed on them.

There is no difference in the web.config

Any ideas what could be causing this?

EDIT:
It works if I remove the async. So if I remove the Generic like explained above, or if I make the method synchronous it works, but not as an async generic class

EDIT2: 
This also works:

```
    private T CallWebMethod<T>(string requestUri)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri).Result;

        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var jsonres = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonres);
    }
```

Here is the full exception:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type '<CallWebMethodAsync>d__b`1' from assembly 'PI.Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=16330d73de5a5293'.
   at Foobar.WebServices.ConfigurationService.<CallWebMethodAsync>d__b`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Foobar.WebServices.ConfigurationService.CallWebMethodAsync[TResponse](String requestUri)
   at Foobar.WebServices.ConfigurationService.<GetMerchantConfigurationAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Foobar.Services.MerchantService.<GetAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Foobar.Api.Controllers.MerchantsController.<Get>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Try rebuilding the entire project again and re-deploying

Comment: I have done, numerous times

Comment: Is the generic type parameter of the WebAPI action? Or is it just an internal method call.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but the error occurs in a separate library to the WebApi. This library has no references to webApi

Comment: Does one of the servers **also** have .NET 4.6 on it?

Comment: No. The 2008 server initially had 4.5.1. I updated it to match the 2012 server ( so I just installed 4.5.2 and it works). None have 4.6

Comment: `'<CallWebMethodAsync>d__e`1'` is there if you look at the assembly in ILSpy? All other DLLs were copied over at the same time?

Comment: This is not the point of the question but the Task.Run thing makes no sense. Just makes the code slower.

Comment: @JonHanna checked that and couldn't see anything out of the ordinary. Also got fusion logs for assembly binding and couldn't see anything different in this DLL than the others

Comment: @usr well spotted  :)

Comment: Can you post the full exception ToString and run peverify on the DLL?

Comment: There are too many possible reasons you could see the error. You need to provide more detail. If not a [mcve] then at least the full exception information (including all inner exceptions!). I will note that your usage of `Task.Run()` is bizarre to me. Using `Task.Run()` seems pointless there; why not just `HttpResponseMessage result = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri);`? I don't see why not doing it that way should cause an exception, but at the very least your version seems strange.

Comment: @usr All Classes and Methods in the dll verified by peverify

Comment: try run the aspnet_iisreg of proper ver on the iis

Comment: @Kelmen I tried aspnet_regiis -iru but you cannot run this on windows 2012. So I went into the server manager, add roles and features and I installed everything under Application Server, and Web Server (IIS). Didn't make a difference

Comment: "cannot run this on windows 2012" ? Previously I have some issue on the dev server, same os, I can run the regiis no issue. Did u use elevated admin right in the command prompt when running this regiis?

Comment: @Kelman Here is the output after running aspnet_regiis -iru:  Start installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.34209). This option is not supported on this version of the operating system.  Administrators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Windows Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager management tool, or the dism.exe command line tool.  For more details please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=216771.
Finished installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.34209).

Comment: looks like u missing turn on some IIS feature for ASP.NET, review ur IIS installation settings. I can't tell exactly what is needed, but it's not really hard to figure out.